# Intellij Docker debugger hangs with message "Warning: validating auto-detected connection"

Tags: docker, intellij-idea

This is my first attempt to use Docker in conjunction with Intellij.  I just created a simple Dockerfile.

Then a connection to the local Docker server has been created:

[image]

In the Editor panel I right clicked and selected the "Debug Dockerfile" option:

[image]

Then when selecting "The "Run/Debug Configuration" dialog hangs with the message

```
  Warning: validating auto-detected connection
```

[image]

The dialog is non responsive - I am unable to cancel or OK or interact - for nearly ten minutes before erroring out.

When attempting again a different way - ie connecting to the local Docker server first - the dialog still hangs when trying to open the dockerfile:

[image]

There appears to be a problem with the Docker server connection:

[image]

What might be going on here - and is there a remedy?  I am on *Intellij Ultimate 2021.2* on  *macOS Big Sur*

**Update**
Command line is looking reasonable since the following works:

```
docker build -t tester -f test.Dockerfile  .
```

And then `Docker Images` does show the "tester" images

Comment: Silly question of course, but do you have Docker Desktop for Mac installed? If so, can you open a terminal and change to your project folder (or, wherever your docker file is) and type `docker build --tag myFirstImage -f test.Dockerfile .` followed by `docker run -it --rm myFirstImage`

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer  yes I had run those commands (well v similar) and they were successful on the command line

Comment: Then it must be a problem with your specific server configuration in Idea. You'll need to give us more info about that specific config.

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer The config was all defaults: I've never done this before. But in any case I just posted it in the question